# How to free two objects and leave the keys only from the other?

Tags: javascript

How to free two objects and leave the keys only from the other?

My example:

```js
const first = {
    "name": "John",
    "address": "London"
}

const second = {
    "name": null,
    "email": null
}

const expectedResult = { // address was removed, because does not exist in second2
    "name": "John",
    "email": null
}

const third = {...first, ...second}

if (expectedResult == third) {
    console.log("ok");
} else {
    console.log("wrong");
}

const first2 = {
    "name": "John",
    "email": "john@john.com",
    "address": "London"
}

const second2 = {
    "name": null,
    "email": null
}

const expectedResult2 = { // address was removed, because does not exist in second2
    "name": "John",
    "email": "john@john.com",
}

const third2 = {...first2, ...second2}

if (expectedResult2 == third2) {
    console.log("ok");
} else {
    console.log("wrong");
}
```

If it's easier, then second and second2 can simply be a array (and not an object with nulls) that are to appear as a result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you want to loop over the second and apply the values from the first.

```js
const first = {
    "name": "John",
    "address": "London"
}

const second = {
    "name": null,
    "email": null
}

const result = Object.entries(second).reduce((acc, [key, value]) => {
  acc[key] = key in first ? first[key] : value;
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

Make it into a function:

```js
const cleanUp = (main, sub) => Object.entries(main).reduce((acc, [key, value]) => {
  acc[key] = key in sub ? sub[key] : value;
  return acc;
}, {});


const first = { "name": "John", "address": "London" };
const second = { "name": null, "email": null };

const first2 = { "name": "John", "email": "john@john.com", "address": "London" };
const second2 = { "name": null, "email": null };

const result = cleanUp(second, first);
const result2 = cleanUp(second2, first2);

console.log(result);
console.log(result2);
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue comes from:

1. The null values. To prevent those, you should use a custom method, for example here the `merge` function.
2. They are not exactly the same object. To check them, I'm using `JSON.stringify()`. According to what you compare, maybe you will no longer need it.

```js
function merge(obj1, obj2) {
    answer = {}
    for(key in obj1) {
       if(answer[key] === undefined || answer[key] === null)
          answer[key] = obj1[key];
    }
    for(key in obj2) {
       if(answer[key] === undefined || answer[key] === null)
            answer[key] = obj2[key];
     }
    return answer
}

const first = {
    "name": "John",
    "address": "London"
}

const second = {
    "name": null,
    "email": null
}

const expectedResult = { // address was removed, because does not exist in second2
    "name": "John",
    "address": "London",
    "email": null
}

const third = merge(first, second);

if (JSON.stringify(expectedResult) == JSON.stringify(third)) {
    console.log("ok");
} else {
    console.log("wrong", expectedResult, third);
}
```